# Is "Futuro do pretérito" ever actually used for the "future in the past" literally, or just for conditional structures?

Tags: português-brasileiro, gramática, português-europeu, verbos, tempo-verbal

Is the Portuguese "Futuro do pretérito" ever actually used for the "future in the past" literally, or in modern Portuguese is it just used for conditional structures?

By analogy, the English word "would" is today mainly used for the conditional mood in English, however you can see by looking at it that it comes from the past of "will".  This meaning of "future in the past" is still visible in structures like reported speech, such as "He told me he would come".

This can also be formed periphrastically with "to be going" as in "He told me he was going to come", and indeed, for most uses of "future in the past", we use the periphrastic form.

Portuguese has almost exactly the same phenomenon (peculiar, since English isn't a Romance language).  Except that whereas English has a modal and a "go" periphrasis Portuguese has an inflected and a "go" periphrasis.

So you have, loosely speaking (usages are different in other situations, but for the sake of analogy):

> Eu jogarei     =   I will play
>   Eu jogaria     =   I would play
>   Eu vou jogar =   I am going to play
>   Eu ia jogar    =   I was going to play

**My question is this:** while I am very familiar with the use of *jogaria* in conditional structures (in fact, I believe in Portugal you don't call it the *futuro do pretérito* but the *condicional*), are there any uses of this conjugation to mean an actual future of the past in the sense of "He told me he would be here" or "I knew that you would do well".  I know I can say *Ele falou que ia estar aqui* and *Eu sabia que você ia mandar bem* but can I say this, or something like this, using the *pretérito perfeito* forms?

I'm interested in any dialect of portuguese, thanks in advance

Comment: I really do not understand the issue here because the "was going to come" and "would come" happen to be very straightforward in Portuguese "ia vir" and "viria". Is your native language somehow interfering with this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the *futuro do pretérito* is also used meaning "future of the past". Some examples:

> Bolsas foram deixadas nos estabelecimentos, como garantia de que mulher voltaria. [[A Gazeta]](http://gazetaonline.globo.com/_conteudo/2012/03/noticias/a_gazeta/dia_a_dia/1142895-mulher-abastece-e-sai-de-posto-sem-pagar.html)
>
> Ele me disse que viria de vez em quando e me ajudaria com o dinheiro da ração. [[Folha]](https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/cotidiano/2017/06/1889379-dona-de-pensao-que-seria-demolida-resgata-caes-e-gatos-da-cracolandia.shtml)
>
> [...] e ela me disse que viria com uma saia de vinil. [[Chic]](http://chic.uol.com.br/moda/noticia/com-looks-parecidos-atrizes-camila-morgado-e-carolina-ferraz-comentam-seus-habitos-de-consumo)

And this usage is also mentioned in the [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/futuro_do_pret%C3%A9rito) (emphasis added):

> **futuro do pretérito** *m* (*uncountable*)
>
> (*grammar, chiefly Brazil*) a Portuguese verb form used to express the conditional tense, **futurity from a past perspective** or to make polite requests

I'd say that the reason one doesn't encounter this construction too often is a preference for the periphrastic form - a preference which is rather prevalent, at least in pt-br, for instance, also for the *pretérito mais-que-perfeito* ("tinha tentado" is much more common than "tentara"), and for the future tense ("vou tentar" vs. "tentarei").

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm thinking harder and harder about this and now I've thought about it more, it's hard for me to get my head around the actual conceptual differences between "I was going to buy the boat (but didn't)" and "I would have bought the boat" in my own language, let alone the difference between "Eu ia comprar o barco mas não dava" and "Eu compraria o barco".  The line between "future of the past" and "hypothetical" aren't nearly as clear as I was thinking, so I really need to think through what I'm trying to ask here

Comment: I'll get back to this in a while once I've straightened it all out in my own head.  But again, thanks very much for the response

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe I can help a bit. The conditional doesn't need the "would", it's valid to say "if the plane is late tomorrow, I will miss your wedding" or "if you gave her the medicine, she survived"; you need "would" to denote something *unreal/unlikely/hypothetical* only. So, "I would have bought the boat" already implies you didn't, while "I was going to buy the boat" has indeed to be complemented by "but didn't" to convey that (you could say instead "that's why I'd bought a license"). You can check about the [3 conditionals](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/conditional2.htm).

Comment: @Some_Guy Also, I'd say there's no real difference between "Eu ia comprar o barco, mas não deu" and "Eu compraria o barco, mas não deu.". To clearly denote either unreal conditional or future of the past you need context, such as "mas não deu" or, instead, "Eu não sabia na época que compraria meu próprio barco assim que completasse 16 anos.".  Besides "compraria" one can also say "iria comprar", "viria a comprar", or, more informally, "ia comprar".

Comment: The line between "future of the past" and "hypothetical" isn't clear because they may coincide. Let's take the example "Bolsas foram deixadas nos estabelecimentos, como garantia de que mulher voltaria."; we presume the owner of the "estabelecimento" had the return of the woman as a hypothesis. On the  other hand, there's no such a hypothesis in this sentence: "Naquele tempo, eu não sabia que me casaria com ela vinte anos depois." ("That time, I didn't know I would marry her twenty years later.")